# groupby pandas dataframe and get mean value of every X seconds - Python

Tags: python, pandas

There is a dataframe like below:

| Category | Time (s) |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| B | 3 |
| B | 3 |
| B | 4 |
| B | 4 |
| C | 5 |
| C | 6 |
| C | 7 |
| C | 8 |

How can I group by this data frame and get the mean Value of the last X (for example 2) seconds.
The output should be like:

| Category | Time (s) |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 4 |
| C | 7.5 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
out=df.groupby('Category',as_index=False)['Time (s)'].agg(lambda x:x.tail(2).mean())
```

**OR**

```
grouped=df.groupby('Category')['Time (s)']
out=grouped.nth([-1,-2]).groupby(level=0).mean().reset_index()
```

output of `out`:

```
    Category    Time (s)
0   A           1.0
1   B           4.0
2   C           7.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby` with `tail`:

```
print (df.groupby("Category").apply(lambda d: d.tail(2).mean()))

          Time (s)
Category          
A              1.0
B              4.0
C              7.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with list position

```
df.groupby('Category')['Time (s)'].apply(lambda x : np.mean(x[-2:]))
Out[7]: 
Category
A    1.0
B    4.0
C    7.5
Name: Time (s), dtype: float64
```